# list all packages from which distribution

Tags: apt, dpkg

With `dpkg -l` I can see all installed packages on debian.

But I have installed some packages from jessie and some from stretch.

How do I find out, which packages are installed from stretch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`apt-show-versions`](https://tracker.debian.org/apt-show-versions), from the eponymous package, will tell you what release your installed packages are from.

`apt list --installed` will also tell you this, without needing to install a new package.